# git rebase without force push or deleting the remote branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have a main branch which is named as `develop`. I checked out a branch from it named as `feature`. I made few changes in `feature` branch and pushed it to remote. I was continuing the work on `feature` branch, but in the meantime there're new commits in `develop` branch.

I needed to add those commit in the `feature` branch. For that I have chosen to rebase, instead of merge. Then when I tried to push the new rebased `feature` branch, it gave me an error that it can't be fast-forwarded.

So, I had 2 options, either to force push or delete the remote branch and then push the new branch.

Since the force push was disabled by the admins, I left with the second option of deleting the remote branch and then pushing the new branch. That deleting part didn't sound right to me, so I was wondering if there's any other way to do it without deleting, force push or creating a merge commit?

Someone suggested me that I can rebase the `feature` branch on remote, instead on local from `develop`, but I couldn't find how can I do that?

So in short, I wanted to know what flow of commands should I follow for rebasing changes from `develop` to `feature` without force push or deleting the remote branch?

Comment: Why you are not try take a pull from origin develop in your feature branch then push

Comment: Force pushing is essentially the same as deleting a branch on the remote and then pushing it (as if it was a new branch).

Comment: @GovindParashar That creates a merge commit. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: @alfunx Yes, I understand, that's why I wanted to try some other alternatives.

Comment: @noob You can't avoid force pushing in this situation since you're rewriting history. That is even true for "rebase the `feature` branch on remote, instead on local from `develop`" (not quite sure what you mean with that, but doesn't really matter). It's either force push or merge.